# MySQL Select cheapest latest ASK price

Tags: mysql

Guys i have this structure in a table:

[image]

The table holds a history of prices for set of Market Links connected to Exchanges. The data is continuously growing - every x seconds new prices are added.

I need to find out which **MarketLink** is **currently** the **cheapest** (ASK price)

What should be the query?

Comment: What means cheapest and latest in the same time?

Comment: Updated the question.
There are several market links storing their Prices at once in the Table.
I need to find out which market link is currently the cheapest (ASK price)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order your result by latest time ie. epoch

```
SELECT id,MarketLink,MIN(Ask) from tbl_name ORDER by epoch DESC LIMIT 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Hope it helps you out.

```
SELECT MIN(Ask) cheapest from tbl_name;
```

EDIT

In order to achieve this, You'll have to keep track of the records that you've already scanned, say for example you can use ID or a timestamp, every time you query. So while querying, what you're supposed to do is, use that ID or a timestamp as a benchmark and check for the Min(Ask) after that Id or timestamp.

Comment: Why do you need an `ORDER BY` if you only get back one result?

Comment: Yes, you're rite, thats my bad.! Thanks for pointing out that. Just edited my answer

Comment: This will return the minimum Ask in the history, what i need is LATEST(by ID) minimum price.